# Implement countall in prolog

Tags: prolog

Need prolog code to implement countall(List1, List2, N), which counts the number of any element in List1 in List2

Test cases for checking code

```
   ?- countall([a], [b, a, c, a], Number).
   Number=2.

   ?- countall([a, b], [b, b, a, c, a], Number).
   Number=4.

   ?- countall([a], [b, c, d], Number).
   Number=0.

   ?- countall([e, e], [e], Number).
   Number=2.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
countall(List1, List2, Count):-
    findall(Elem, (member(Elem, List1), member(Elem, List2)), Matches),
    length(Matches, Count).
```

"Find all the ways Elem is something found in both List1 and List2, gather them up and count them".

```
?- countall([a], [b, a, c, a], Number).
             ^       ^
             ^             ^
```

and

```
?- countall([a, b], [b, b, a, c, a], Number).
             ^             ^
             ^                   ^
                ^    ^
                ^       ^
```

Comment: Tried the code and it worked perfectly. Thanks a lot @Tessellatingheckler

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution without using `findall` and `length` is to use `member` and an accumulator to count the occurrences:

```
countall(List1,List2,Number):- 
          countall(List1,List2,0,Number).

countall(_,[],Number,Number).
countall(List1,[H|List2],Acc,Number):-
          member(H,List1),
          AccNew is Acc + 1,
          countall(List1,List2,AccNew,Number).
countall(List1,[H|List2],Acc,Number):-
          not(member(H,List1)),
          countall(List1,List2,Acc,Number).
```

If you want and if you know what you are doing, you can replace the `not(member(H,List1))` in the 3rd clause auf `countall/4` by a cut in the 2nd clause.